# Zendesk iOS SDK: Customize UI for Answer Bot engine

Tags: ios, zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

I have added the Zendesk iOS Answerbot SDK to an app and I would like to:

1. Customize the initial messages
2. Direct the user to a different view when the "Leave a message" button is tapped

This is the code I have so far:

```
do {
      let messagingConfiguration = MessagingConfiguration()
      let answerBotEngine = try AnswerBotEngine.engine()
      let supportEngine = try SupportEngine.engine()
      let viewController = try Messaging.instance.buildUI(engines: [answerBotEngine, supportEngine], configs: [messagingConfiguration])

      let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Close", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(dismissView))
      viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button

      let helpController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

      self.present(helpController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }
```

This is what the default UI looks like:

[AnswerBot UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFjaW.png)

Zendesk AnswerBot for iOS documentation: https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/classic-web-widget-sdks/unified-sdk/ios/answer_bot_engine/

It looks like the customization options are limited based on this documentation:
https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/classic-web-widget-sdks/unified-sdk/ios/customizing_the_look/

You can name the bot like below, but not finding examples of much else.

```
let messagingConfiguration = MessagingConfiguration()
messagingConfiguration.name = "Bot Name"
```

It seems like you can use the API and build your own UI, but I was wondering if my questions are possible in the default SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, you can in fact override any string that Zendesk provides by doing the following:

> If your project does not yet have a Localizable.strings file with the different language variants, you can create one by following these steps:
> In Xcode, select File > New > File
> Select Resource in the iOS category in the sidebar
> Select Strings File from the files and click Next.
> Name the file Localizable and click Create.

[Reference](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/classic-web-widget-sdks/unified-sdk/ios/localize_text/#customize-existing-strings)

For example, you can override the SupportSDK greeting message by just adding this to your localizable file:

```
"ios.SupportEngine.greeting.message" = "Please remain calm the police is coming ‍♀️";
```

But if you support more than one language you should override in all localizable files.

Take a look at the massive list of all of the localizable strings you can [override](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/classic-web-widget-sdks/support-sdk/ios/localize_text/#list-of-strings).

Regarding your second question, as far as I know, every logic inside the Zendesk chat does not allow extra configuration to show other views. Since you can't override the click of `Leave a Message` since you can't access that component from your app.

I hope I could help in your case, have a great week.